# Getting all the files names from folder to a scroll area in QT

Tags: qt, qt5.6

I am new to QT and I want to know how I can get all the file names from a folder to a scroll area and allow the users to click on it to do a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should read some documentation to understand how Qt works.

To get all files in directory, you can use [entryInfoList()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryInfoList) method of **QDir**. It is simple to use **QListWidget** to show this files.

You can create function to get files something like

```cpp
QDir dir(path);
for (const QFileInfo &file : dir.entryInfoList(QDir::Files))
{
    QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(file.fileName());
    item->setData(Qt::UserRole, file.absolutePath()); // if you need absolute path of the file
    listWidget->addItem(item);
}
```

If you don't want to use absolute path then you can use just [entryList()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryList) method.

```cpp
QDir dir(path);
for (const QString &filename : dir.entryList(QDir::Files)
    listWidget->addItem(filename);
```

And connect to [itemClicked()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked) signal of **QListWidget** to do something when the user has clicked  the entry.